# Property "usb" does not exist on type "Navigator" in angular2 typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using below code just to see devices connected on usb port. Getting error "Property usb does not exist on type Navigator" at compile time when I run 'ng serve' command in command prompt.

```
ngOnInit() {
    async () => {
        let devices = await navigator.usb.getDevices();
        devices.forEach(device => {
          // Add |device| to the UI.
          console.log(device);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The best solution is to use `@types/w3c-web-usb` typing package.

Add it to your project using either yarn:

`yarn add --dev @types/w3c-web-usb`

or npm

`npm install --save-dev @types/w3c-web-usb`

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: after I ran ```npm install --save-dev @types/w3c-web-usb```, the compiler still showed ```Property 'usb' does not exist on type 'Navigator'``` when building. How to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

```sh
yarn add -D @types/w3c-web-usb
```

or

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/w3c-web-usb
```

Then, add the following directive at the top of your typescript file:

```js
/// <reference types="w3c-web-usb" />
```

Comment: Lost a couple of hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: …or just put `/// <reference types="w3c-web-usb" />` within an `index.d.ts` file

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that `navigator.usb` exists, you can extend the interface to include some type information for it:

```
interface Navigator {
    usb: {
        getDevices(): any[];
    }
}
```

This will resolve the compile time error (but will result in a runtime error if `usb` isn't there).

The interface needs to be placed in the same common root... so if you are within a module, you may need to use:

```
declare global {
    interface Navigator {
        usb: {
            getDevices(): any[];
        }
    }
}
```